# gostaria de saber como eu coloco esse cabeçalho fixo igual o menu deste site junto a logo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero que meu cabeçalho da pagina (logo menu etc.) fique fixo ao rolar a página para baixo. Igualmente o menu com logo desse site (StackOverflow), que quando eu rolo a tela ele fica no mesmo lugar. Gostaria de um modelo em html e css, não faço ideia de como isso opera.

Comment: Tente usar a propriedade CSS `position: sticky`. Você acha mais sobre ela neste link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @VictorStafusa na verdade é `position: fixed`

Comment: Mas a propriedade é esta mesmo.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho `position: fixed` e `position: sticky` são parecidos mas são diferentes. O que o autor da pergunta parece estar querendo é o `sticky`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendi... Achei que fosse o fixed o mais apropriado. =) vou dar uma olhada melhor.

Comment: Top:0; position:sticky

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias dúvidas similares a sua. Porém acho que nenhuma aborda a diferença entre `position:sticky` e `position:fixed`

**position:fixed**: sempre fixa um elemento em alguma posição em seu contêiner de rolagem ou na viewport. Não importa como você rola seu contêiner, ele permanecerá na mesma posição e não afetará o fluxo de outros elementos dentro do contêiner.

**position:sticky**: sem entrar em detalhes específicos, `position:sticky` basicamente atua como `position:relative` até que um elemento seja rolado além de um deslocamento específico, em cujo caso ele se transforma position: fixed, fazendo com que o elemento "grude" em sua posição em vez de ser rolado para fora da vista. Ele eventualmente se solta quando é rolado de volta para sua posição original. Pelo menos, é assim que eu entendo isso em teoria. ***OBS:*** `position:sticky` ainda é uma classe experimental e não funciona no IE, inicialmente foi desenvolvida para criar menus e headers para otimizar sites e sistemas para dispositivos mobile onde podemos ter um `scroll` vertical muito longo. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Exemplo de uso de Menu com **position:sticky**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 80px;
}
.cor h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
.cor {
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h3>Meu header</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</header>
<section>
    <nav class="cor"><h1>NavBar #1</h1></nav>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
```

Exemplo de uso de Menu com **position:fixed**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 80px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.cor {
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 9;
}
.topo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
```

```html
<nav class="topo"><h1>Menu #1</h1></nav>
<section>
    <h3>Teste barra</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1 class="cor">teste #2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
```

Documentação oficial **W3C**: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#position-property

Documentação **Mozilla**: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

*Fonte do texto*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501919/difference-between-positionsticky-and-positionfixed