# Position: fixed, usar ou não usar? Substitutos

Tags: html, css, pwa

Recentemente assisti uma palestra do [Sérgio Lopes](http://sergiolopes.org/palestra-mobile-web/#slide-esquecer) , na qual ele fala que **NÃO** se deve usar position fixed no mobile. Segundo ele, esse position traz enormes problemas no navegador do celular, como o que acontece quando dar zoom.

No entanto, estou enfrentando um problema agora: preciso colocar uma barra fixa no fundo da página, que nem aquele [bottom-bar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#) do material design.

E agora, como fazer? Usar um js pesadão para manter ela sempre lá? Dividir em duas divs, e colocar a de cima com o conteúdo e width fixo e overflow, e a de baixo usar para o bottom bar?

Ou cagar para o Sergio?

Outra coisa que não faz parte dessa pergunta: nos apps nativos não existe zoom, então se tratando de um pwa, que é like-app, por que não desabilitar o zoom??

Comment: Ele tem os seus motivos pessoais, mas nunca existiu tal regra.

Comment: Realmente, mas os argumentos são bons. Então, se ele disse para não usar, como ele faria esse posicionamento?

Comment: Eu usuária sua dica de usar div separadas,e fazer scroll em somente uma delas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode trocar o fixed por `position:sticky` apesar do suporte dos browsers ainda não ser muito grande.

- Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position
- Suporte dos Browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky *(nao funciona no IE)*

**E lembre-se que essa palestra é de 2013!! 5 anos no passado!**

**OBS:** O IE 7 já aceitava `position:fixed` https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Nessa resposta tem algumas detalhes da diferença entre `position:sticky` e `position:fixedhttps` [gostaria de saber como eu coloco esse cabeçalho fixo igual o menu deste site junto a logo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285460/gostaria-de-saber-como-eu-coloco-esse-cabe%C3%A7alho-fixo-igual-o-menu-deste-site-jun/285485#285485)

Sobre o Zoom isso é uma questão de acessibilidade e limitar o uso dele é péssimo para quem tem problema de visão, além disso existem apps mobiles nativos que dão zoom na tela de qq forma... Mas eu particularmente cagaria para o Sergio e faria com Fixed...

> A variety of methods allow the user to control content size on mobile
>   devices with small screens. At the browser level these methods are
>   generally available to assist a wide audience of users. At the
>   platform level these methods are available as accessibility features
>   to serve people with visual impairments or cognitive disabilities.

Aqui tem o *Guide Line* oficial da **WCAG 2.0** e **W3C/WAI** falando sobre o Zoom em dispositivos mobile https://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/#zoom-magnification

Answer (score 2):

Cara, realmente a palestra de 2013 já tá bem desatualizada. Não caga pra mim não, mas pode cagar pra palestra hahaha.

O cenário era bem caótico em 2013. Nada funcionava com fixed em praticamente nenhum browser. **As coisas melhoraram bastante desde então**.

Mas continuam um tanto caóticas.

A melhor referência sobre `fixed` em mobile que você encontra hoje são os testes detalhadíssimos do [@ppk](https://twitter.com/ppk):

https://quirksmode.org/css/css2/mobile.html#link1

Repare que vários browsers modernos já suportam `fixed` com certa segurança. Mas tem os antigos, e tem os outros tipos de navegadores. Recomendo olhar lá pra entender as limitações atuais, e pra você decidir quais navegadores quer suportar.

---

Sobre o zoom, eu ainda defendo que sites não bloqueiem o zoom. É uma questão de acessibilidade. Realmente as Apps nativas não permitem zoom; isso é um bug. Ainda bem que na Web conseguimos ser melhores que eles :-P

Comment: Fala Sérgio, legal vc comentar aqui, e que bom que vc não levou para o lado pessoal. Esse tipo de debate só enriquece a comunidade. Apesar da metáfora qq um que contribua para o conhecimento alheio merece meu reconhecimento! []´s